# Is sending fall semester transcripts beneficial even if grades show a downtrend?

Tags: graduate-admissions, united-states

I received my undergraduate transcript with the fall semester grades a week back; I was wondering whether I should use it over an old transcript for my application to grad school in the US (top 10 in physics).

Reasons for sending old transcript (latest: spring grades from junior year):

- Spring semester showed good grades.
- Higher CGPA (+0.05 on a scale of 10.0).
- Subsequent fall semester shows a downturn in grades (-0.7 on a scale of 10.0).

Reason for sending new transcript (latest: fall grades from senior year):

- Shows advanced physics and math courses; I have talked a bit about these courses and a project in my Statement of Purpose.

One reason for the less than ideal performance in the fall semester is taking a lot of theory courses; however, I have not "explained" this in my SOP as there aren't any failing grades (or really poor performance).

Does the choice between the two transcripts really matter or am I overthinking this? If it matters, I am an international applicant from India.

P.S. I have completed the essential courses earlier so that is not a factor to be considered.

Edit: As pointed in a comment below, this question is not a duplicate as my grades are quite good (sorry for not mentioning this in the original post).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How does the admissions process work for Ph.D. programs in the US, particularly for weak or borderline students?](http://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/38237/how-does-the-admissions-process-work-for-ph-d-programs-in-the-us-particularly)

Comment: Not a duplicate as my grades are quite good (sorry for not mentioning this in the original post).

Comment: Just curious about this GPA system (I am in a 4-point system.) Do you mean the GPA dropped by -0.7, or do you mean getting a GPA of -0.7 out of 10? I feel that the absolute position of your GPA matters.

Comment: @Penguin_Knight, I meant that it my semester GPA dropped from 9.5 to 8.8. Overall my CGPA dropped by 0.05 on a scale of 10. I was not sure if it was a good idea to put my exact grades.

Comment: If your CGPA is already high enough, dropping 0.05 won't matter (say from 9.48 to 9.43). However, if your CGPA is already low (say 6.2/10), then your question is a duplicate of the linked question.

Comment: @scaaahu, I understand. My CGPA is fairly high (9/10) so it is not a duplicate.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You should include the latest transcript.  The reason is simple: that is now your true transcript, and replaces the prior transcript.  If you don't include the most recent grades, then the universities where you are applying may wonder why: did you have terrible grades? Were you not attending classes at all?

Your current transcript is your transcript.  Just include it, and don't play games about it.

Comment: " If you don't include the most recent grades, then the universities where you are applying may wonder why" - thanks, I did not think of that.

Comment: This is also important - especially considering I bet they asked for "your most recent transcript". Essentially it could be taken as lying if you provided an earlier version.

Answer (score 2):

Generally the grad school you are applying will have guidelines on the specific transcripts to be sent. This will include *all* your previous grade cards including your high school and expect them to be checked thoroughly.

On an ethical point of view, hiding *relevant* information especially in *academia* for the sake of gaining a sweet spot is not advisable and most of the times are not going to pay well.

Comment: I asked the question only because the school in question does not have any such guidelines. While I understand the point about not wanting to "hide" information, I don't think this is a particularly egregious case.

Comment: No American University i know of asks for high school transcripts for graduate applicants.